# Is it possible to set Action to Explicit Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

For this code, 'localIntent' seems Explicit Intent directed to 'SecondActivity.class'. But it also seems that it's action has been set as 'SAMPLE'. In this case, is this still Explicit Intent? And when this type of Intent usually is used for?

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class).setAction("SAMPLE");
startActivity(localIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Intent of Android, there are only two types like this:

> - Explicit Intents have specified a component (via setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which
>     provides the exact class to be run. Often these will not include any
>     other information, simply being a way for an application to launch
>     various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the
>     application.
> - Implicit Intents have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the
>     available components is best to run for that intent.

So, whether you set component or set class, that will be explicit intent.([read more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW))